# in gridview update coding i am getting following error?

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my update event code :

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }

    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    int Label11 =Convert.ToInt32(((Label)row.FindControl("Label11")).Text);// this is the line m getting error in
    int Label12 = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)row.FindControl("Label12")).Text);
    int Label13 = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)row.FindControl("Label13")).Text);
    TextBox TextBox4 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox4");
    TextBox TextBox5 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox5");
    TextBox TextBox6 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox6");
    TextBox TextBox7 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox7");
    TextBox TextBox8 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox8");
    TextBox TextBox9 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox9");
    TextBox TextBox10 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox10");
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update monthly set date='" + TextBox4.Text + "',salary='" + TextBox5.Text + "',ta='" + TextBox6.Text + "',contigency='" + TextBox7.Text + "',nrc='" + TextBox8.Text + "',institcharges='" + TextBox9.Text + "',others='" + TextBox10.Text + "' where autoid='" + Label12 + "'", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();
    grid_show();
```

the error i m getting is FormatException was unhandled bu user code
Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: First of all your code is apt to be a target of SQL injection. Use ORM framework like Entity Framework or use parameterized query. This is a recipe for disaster. User `TryParse` method for primitive datatypes to avoid exception and prepare your parameters from there.

Comment: @JigarPatel: It's probably just worth writing both of those points up as an answer...

Comment: jigar hey m new to this method can u tell me how to use this i have always used convert.toin32 for conversion.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you have typed here. At least type your question in proper English if you want answers from community.

Answer (score 1):

Use TryParse method available for Primitive data types. Explaining SQL injection and ORM framework is beyond the scope of this answer.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=TryParse&ac=8

```
void Main()
{
    //TryParse function signature
    //bool TryParse(String, Int32) 
    //Above method is for Integer. There are similar methods for all primitive data types

    //TryParse takes String value as an input and parameter as reference

    //Integer example
    int result;
    bool success = int.TryParse("10", out result);
    if(success) Console.WriteLine("Good value {0}", result);


    //DateTime example
    DateTime dtResult;
    success = DateTime.TryParse("01/10/2013", out dtResult);
    if(success) Console.WriteLine("Good date {0}", dtResult);
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur help ..!! anyhow if there is anyone who can help ...will be great !